# Web-based CMS for passwords

Tags: cms, self-hosted, password-manager

I'm working at a creative agency and at the moment, all the passwords are written in some random Word document on our NAS.

We are looking for a cleaner solution, where we can store passwords and maybe some more additional infos like contact persons of each client and so on. We are also thinking of a Slack-integration in the future with an app or a bot.

It should be free and also hosted at our servers.

Usually, I'd just go for WordPress and do everything by hand. But maybe there is already something available, which does what I want and / or comes with the possibility for custom features.
So just before I start coding an own WordPress theme, I thought that it would be a good idea to ask here first.

Comment: Storing passwords plaintext on whatever server is a security disaster (what if someone breaks in and gets hold of the list?) Would a secure variant where the password file is stored encrypted (e.g. on a network share) be an option? That's what I found used in most companies I've worked with. Using e.g. KeePass, you could continue storing the (encrypted) database on your NAS – and the structure/forms that application offers would also allow for the additional infos you mention. And it is cross-platform, so one could even use it on a mobile device if wanted ;)

Comment: As Izzy commented, you should *never* store passwords as such. Learn about hashing, salting, and proper ways to handle passwords and user-authentication.

Comment: @BasilBourque I believe this question is about storing passwords that are needed for authenticating with other services, rather than authenticating one's own users. So the original password is needed, not a hash.

Comment: @Kodiologist I see. The Question should clarify that they are tracking passwords they have been given, not passwords that they are handing out.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider https://1password.com/

I believe they allow you to either use a cloud based tool or host the data yourself and also have an option for teams.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features, pretty unknown, of [Keepass](https://keepass.info/) is the ability to work from a shared drive (the data file being put on just a shared folder). The program takes care of sync entries if several people "writes" new passwords or entries so it's a simple solution (you can read more in the manual).